# select for other than -1 and not the same value as negative value

Tags: mysql

```
ID| uid | val1 | val2
---------------------
1 | 80 | -1  | -1 
2 | 81 | 45  | -1
3 | 82 | 99  | -1
4 | 81 | -45 | -1
5 | 82 | 99  | 50
6 | 83 | 55  | 70
7 | 83 | -55 | -70
8 | 81 | 41  | -1
9 | 83 | -1  | 80
```

don't select these: 
- other than -1
- if there is the same positive and negative value (with minus sign -- for example in this table it is 45 and negative value -45) etc

Hello I have this table. Please how should I write query if I want to get this?

```
[1]
  uid=81
  val1=41
  val2=

[2]
  uid=82
  val1=99
  val2=50

[3]
  uid=83
  val1=
  val2=80
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff is this comment still valid? You answered below.

Comment: @kermit . . . I think I figured out a reasonable interpretation of what the OP is looking for.  However, the OP has not responded to the answer, so I am unable to say that I really do understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this do what you want?

```
select t.*
from table t
where val1 <> -1 and val2 <> -1 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from table t2
                  where (t.val1 = -1 or t2.val1 = - t.val1) and
                        (t.val2 = -1 or t2.val2 = - t.val2)
                 );
```

I think the key is `not exists` to filter out the negative-paired rows.